# how to open default application file with ruby?

Tags: ruby

how to open default application file?

for example, I will open the file then open Picture.png is the image viewer.

how do I do that with a ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to the "launchy" gem

Install the gem:

```
$ gem install launchy
```

Then in your Ruby program do the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'launchy'

Launchy.open("/path/to/image.png")
```